# Printing a range of pages in MS Word using OLE (Imprimir em ole object (word application) com delphi)

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to print a range of pages from my Ole Object object, but it's not working for me - I get a "type mismatch" exception when the call to Doc.PrintOut executes.

Can anyone help me to avoid this error? Below is the code used in tests:

```
  if (OpenDialog1.Execute) then
    begin
        // Cria objeto principal de controle do Word
        WinWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
        if (not (VarIsEmpty(WinWord))) then
           begin
              // Mostra o Word
              try
                  WinWord.Visible := false;
                  Docs := WinWord.Documents;
                  // Abre um documento
                  Doc := Docs.Open(OpenDialog1.FileName);
                  //Doc.PrintOut(false, Range, 1, 2);
                  //Doc.PrintOut(Copies := 2);
                  vFrom := 1;
                  vTo := 2;
                  Doc.PrintOut(Background := false, Append := false, Range :=       wdPrintFromTo, OutputFileName := EmptyParam, From := vFrom, To := vTo);
                  // erro recebido: tipo não correspondente
              finally
                  // Fecha o Word
                  WinWord.Quit;
           end;
    end;

    showmessage('Fim!');
end;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is an English-speaking site.  There aren't many people here who speak Portuguese. (Sinto muito, este é um site de língua Inglês. Não há muitas pessoas aqui que falam Português.)

Comment: Try portuguese SO: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @user3772322: I think the only thing English-only readers might need to know is what "tipo não correspondente" means.  Google Translate renders it as "no corresponding type".  Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: Whoever downvoted: Did this q really deserve it just because an error message is quoted not in English?  The intent of the code could hardly be clearer ...

Comment: Why do you initial argument variable in your Doc.PrintOut ?

Comment: @MartynA: Have a look at the original version of the post.  That downvote was already there when I posted my comment above.  Looks like things have been cleaned up since then.

Comment: Even fixed up it deserves the down vote because there is no problem description. Just "it is not working".

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: Sorry, I hope you didn't take it that I was assuming the d/v was yours.  Far from it.  I've seen you time and again go the extra mile to help people here and the other day didn't somebody comment that an answer of yours was more like how SO is supposed to be than the d/voting and negativity that seems a bit prevalent lately in the Delphi sections?

Comment: @David: Uh?  It has what is apparently the exact error message, even if it's not in English.

Comment: @MartynA it is hidden away and not in English. This is a poor question. It's great that you've answered. I upvote that. But it's not a good question. We don't want poor questions to be upvoted. It gives them false prominence. Pity upvoting is no good.

Comment: @David, thanks.  I certainly agree that poor (and/or lazy) questions shouldn't be encouraged, otherwise the place would soon be neck deep with them. It's more the question of (in)consistency that bothers me.  It seems to me that you and a number of others incl Mason often go a lot further out of your way than I had to in this case to read past the OP's words to get to the nub of the problem.  By comparison, those who mother tongue isn't English seem to get a bit short-changed sometimes.

Comment: @martyna I'll happily downvote a Q and answer it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code in D7, using the English-language version of Office2007.

I get an exception error on Doc.PrintOut which is Delphi's usual "Type Mismatch".  By experimenting with the arguments passed to Doc.PrintOut, I think it's the

```
Range := wdPrintFromTo
```

that's causing the exception, because a "range" would normally be a block of text, whereas wdPrintFromTo is a numeric constant (but then, the Word macro I mention below uses a numeric constant for the range, so maybe Word just doesn't like th one you used).

Then, I got Word to record a macro to print the first two pages of a 6-page doc, and found that I could then get your code to work by making these changes:

- replace vFrom and vTo, which I assume are OleVariants, by two integers iFrom and iTo (I don't think that this really matters, just makes it easier to check that the page-range argument is correctly constructed.
- replace the code from "vFrom := [...] to Doc.PrintOut by

  ```
  iFrom := 1;
  iTo := 2;

  Doc.PrintOut(
    Range := wdPrintRangeOfPages,
    Item := wdPrintDocumentContent,
    Copies := 1,
    Pages := IntToStr(iFrom) + '-' + IntToStr(iTo),
    PageType := wdPrintAllPages,
    ManualDuplexPrint := False,
    Collate := True,
    Background := True,
    PrintToFile := False,
    PrintZoomColumn := 0,
    PrintZoomRow := 0,
    PrintZoomPaperWidth := 0,
    PrintZoomPaperHeight := 0
  );
  ```

Obviously, the arguments this PrintOut includes are ones which the Word macro included. and typically some of them would probably be superfluous.

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for your interest.  I wasn't trying to roll back your edit by the one I made immediately afterwards, it was just that yours prompted me to notice a couple of typos.

Comment: I was completely unaware of this type of parameter passing. Turns out it is an OLE feature http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885942/named-optional-parameters-in-delphi

Comment: @Jan Doggen:  Yes, this has been around since automation support was added to Delphi in D2.  Anders Hejlsberg appeared on Borland's area on Compuserve for a week or two after it came out, holding users' hands through their initial excursions into automating OLE objects and explaining that one of the features he'd had to add to the compiler was support for this style of parameter passing.  I imagine Borland had thought the VBers they hoped to attract would expect it and complain if Delphi didn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all!
MartynA, Jan Doggen, David Heffernan, Mason Wheeler and all others!!

I get solution with the code below:

```
<pre><code>
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WinWord, Docs, Doc: Variant;
  vNomeImpressoraPadraoOriginal : string;
  vFrom, vTo : integer;
begin
  if (OpenDialog1.Execute) then
  begin
    try
      // Cria objeto principal de controle do Word
      WinWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      if (not (VarIsEmpty(WinWord))) then
      begin
        // Mostra o Word
        try
          WinWord.Visible := false;
          Docs := WinWord.Documents;
          // Abre um documento
          Doc := Docs.Open(OpenDialog1.FileName);
          vFrom := 1;
          vTo := 2;
          // referência do comando: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176069/EN-US
          Doc.PrintOut(0, 0, '3', '', '1', '2');
          // previous code
          // Doc.PrintOut(Background := false, Append := false, Range :=       wdPrintFromTo, OutputFileName := EmptyParam, From := vFrom, To := vTo);
        finally
          // Fecha o Word
          WinWord.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges := 0);
          WinWord.Quit;

          WinWord := Unassigned;
          Docs := Unassigned;
          Doc := Unassigned;
        end;
      end;

      showmessage('Fim!');
    finally

    end;
  end;
end;
</code></pre>
```

Comment: It's interesting how many different ways there are of getting MS Word to do the same thing - and you've obviously found another.  Glad you got it working.  Anyway, please feel free to "accept" my answer, if you wish, by clicking the accept button to the left of it.  In case you have not come across that before, it benefits both of us by increasing our "reputations" on Stack Overflow a little bit - as your reputation increases, there are more things that you are permitted to do - one of the first is to be able to post comments on other people's questions and answers.