# Passing parameter value to Function or Procedure with random order

Tags: delphi

Is there a way in Delphi to pass parameter value to Function or Procedure with random order, so i don't have to make sure that the order is right.

Example:

```
procedure InsertEmp(ID: Integer;Name: String;Gender: String);
begin
  //Content
end
```

Then I will use this procedure like this:

```
InsertEmp(1,'Zemmy','Male');
```

But if at another time i change the function parameter order like this:

```
procedure InsertEmp(ID: Integer;NickName:String;Name: String;Gender: String);
begin
  //Content
end
```

I have to make position correction to my function as following:

```
InsertEmp(1,'Jim','Zemmy','Male');
```

Can i pass the parameter value without correcting the order? Maybe a way like this:

```
InsertEmp(Gender = 'Male',NickName = 'Jim',ID = 1,Name = 'Zemmy');
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can pass an object/record to circumvent this problem

Comment: The purpose of my question was to keeping me to not did nothing wrong to my Code. But from all of the answer, the solution become more complicated for me.   :D

I think i will accept @fantaghirocco aswer because he give all the conclusion. And i will consider to use Record to organize the parameter like sample he gives.

Comment: Your motivations are wrong. You should not be trying to design functions which can accept arguments in arbitrary order.

Comment: Umm.. sorry for my english.. What i mean, i want to be safe if i change function parameter order, so then the existing caller does not fill the value to wrong parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885942/named-optional-parameters-in-delphi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two or more parameters of the same type, the called procedure cannot determine their meaning.

I think the answer can be a mix of the [whosrdaddy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688006/passing-parameter-value-to-function-or-procedure-with-random-order/#comment53221590_32688006) an the [LU RD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688006/passing-parameter-value-to-function-or-procedure-with-random-order/32688415#32688415).

Using overloading for a record constructor, you can obtain a smart solution.

```
type
  TEmployee = record
    ID: Integer;
    NickName,
    Name,
    Gender: String;
    constructor Create(const AID: Integer; const ANickname, AName, AGender: String); overload;
    constructor Create(const AID: Integer; const AName, AGender: String); overload;
end;

procedure InsertEmp(const AEmployee: TEmployee);
begin
  //Content
end;

constructor TEmployee.Create(const AID: Integer; const ANickname, AName, AGender: String);
begin
  ID := AID;
  Nickname := ANickName
  Name := AName;
  Gender := AGender;
end;

constructor TEmployee.Create(const AID: Integer; const AName, AGender: String);
begin
  Create(AID, '', AName, AGender);
end;
```

---

```
var
  myEmployee: TEmployee;

begin
  myEmployee := TEmployee.Create(1, 'Zemmy', 'Male');
  InsertEmp(myEmployee);
  . . .
  myEmployee := TEmployee.Create(1, 'Jim', 'Zemmy', 'Male');
  InsertEmp(myEmployee);
end.
```

Comment: What is the reason for using the pointer? Why not `procedure InsertEmp( const Employee: TMyRec );`?

Comment: The overloaded constructors make no sense. You move the problem of the question into the constructor. Just use constructors if you really need them (f.i. guard the ID value). Fill all other values using the fields or properties.

Comment: @Sir Rufo no reason why to use the pointer indeed, it's an habitude using Win API... but I don't get the reason why *overloaded constructors make no sense* here: it seems to me it can solve in an elegant manner with a little bit of refactoing, isn't it?

Comment: Constructors here make no sense, because the use case here is a DTO. If it were a Value Object then the constructor will make sense, because a Value Object has to be immutable.

Comment: @Sir Rufo I agree whith hat: in my intentions it was only a way to write less code :-p

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll try to take into account your comment with the SirRufo's in my future coding approaches. Thank you

Comment: FWIW, I regard record constructors as the spawn of Satan. They make you think that a call to `Free` is needed and that an object has been created that lives on the heap. Far better, in my view, is a static class method with a nam like `New` that returns a newly initialised instance of the record.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I like `Empty` instead of `New` combined with an equal operator to have a guard like `if Employee = TEmployee.Empty then raise EArgumentException.Create();`

Comment: @SirRufo Well, `New` will accept arguments so it's not really the same as `Empty`. As for `Empty`, I'd use `Default(T)` to get a default initialised value. Personally, those arg checks would not appeal to me since they'd just waste time but then my code base tends to be quite perf sensitive.

Comment: @SirRufo I got the reason why *overloaded constructors make no sense*: answer edited. I was thinking to the edited solution while posting a different  stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple [overloaded procedures/functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions) taking parameters that are slightly different.

```
procedure InsertEmp(id: Integer; name: String; gender: String); overload;
procedure InsertEmp(id: Integer; nickName,name: String; gender: String); overload;
```

For a random parameter order, there are serializing libraries taking strings as input and then parsing them for input values. Simple key-value pairs or JSON are examples.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. If you want to do something like that you can pass a single string in a Key - Value format

```
InsertEmp('Gender=Male,NickName=Jim,ID=1,Name=Zemmy');
```

and then parse it inside you function.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option if you can use only one variable type. Use open arrays. Declare

```
procedure InsertEmp(values: array of string);
```

and pass any parameter like this

```
InsertEmp(['Gender = Male', 'NickName = Jim', 'Name = Zemmy' ...]);
```