# From VBA to Delphi conversion (Optional arguments issue)

Tags: excel, delphi, vba

At the moment I'm converting a project written in VBA to Delphi and have stumbled upon a problem with converting some Subs with `Optional` arguments.
Say, there is a Sub declaration (just an example, actual Subs have up to 10 optional parameters):

```
Sub SetMark
    (x0 As Double, y0 As Double, 
     Optional TextOffset As Integer =5,
     Optional TextBefore As String = "",
     Optional Text As String = "",
     Optional TextAfter As String = "mm",
     Optional Color As String = "FFFFFF",
     Optional ArrowPresent As Boolean = True)
```

That Sub subsequently can be called like this:

```
    Call SetMark (15, 100,,,"135")
    Call SetMark (100, 100, 8,, "My text here..", "")
    'a lot of calls here
```

The `Optional` arguments are very flexible here, you can omit any of them, and you can assign a value to any of them as well. Unlike in Delphi.

```
Procedure SetMark
    (x0: real; y0: real, 
            TextOffset: Integer =5;
     TextBefore: ShortString = '';
     Text: ShortString = '';
     TextAfter: ShortString = 'mm';
     Color: ShortString = 'FFFFFF';
     ArrowPresent: Boolean = True);
```

It seems you cannot just make a copy of VBA call:

```
SetMark (15, 100,,,'135');// error here
```

So, the question is: is there any way to convert that Subs to Delphi procedures keeping the **same** flexibility in parameters? 
My first idea was to use default parameters, but it doesn't work.
As for now it seems in Delphi I will have to pass all the parameters in the list with their values directly but that means a lot of work for reviewing and proper porting of VBA calls.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, you really should not be using `ShortString`. That has been deprecated for many many years. Use the native string type, `string`.

Comment: Also, tangentially, `real` is a legacy type that only really exists for compatibility (it is an alias of `double`).  Better to declare a `double` in the Delphi code, just as the VB code does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any way to convert the VBA subroutines to Delphi procedures, still keeping the same flexibility in parameters?

There is no way to achieve that – that flexibility to omit parameters, other than at the end of the list, simply does not exist.

For methods of automation objects, you can use named parameters, as described here: [Named/optional parameters in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885942/named-optional-parameters-in-delphi) However, I very much recommend that you don't implement your classes as automation objects just to get that functionality.

Whenever you switch between languages, you will find differences that are inconvenient. That is inevitable. The best approach is to try to find the best way to solve the problem in the new language, rather than trying to force idioms from the old language into the new language.

In this case you might want to use [overloaded functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions) or [parameter objects](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) as ways to alleviate this inconvenience.

Comment: Yes. Overloads would be my preferred solution.

Comment: Coulod you please specify how to implement overloading that could tell between calls of specified parameters `Text` and `TextAfter`, for example.

Comment: Well, I'm asking not to get any code from anyone.
I'm sorry if it looks like that.
I'm asking because I think that the overload implementation is just not possible for the given case, and 
you mentioned that it would be a "preferred solution". I just wanted to _learn_ something I don't know...

As far as I could figure, the `overload` works great when one needs to have a procedure/function to accept parameters 
of different types. E.g.:
`function MaxValue(a, b : Integer) : string; Overload;
function MaxValue(a, b : String) : string; Overload;` etc.

Comment: That's fine. But if we want to reproduce, say,  VBA `Call SetMark (15, 100,,,"135")`, what would we do?
(The 3rd parameter here is Text). Something like this?
`procedure SetMark (x0: real; y0: real; Text: string); overload;`
Looks great, but what if we just want to pass x0, y0 and TextAfter?
`procedure SetMark (x0: real; y0: real; TextAfter: string); overload;` 
Which of the implementations above would be called by this:
`SetMark(15, 100,'135');`

Comment: **Will we have either Text='135' or TextAfter='135'?**
That was my question.
It seems to me that 'overload' solution is very limited 
(in the original VBA you would just put in another comma for this to work.) 
I would stick to parameter objects, but
Delphi 7 does not support constructors within records.

Comment: You don't need record constructors and in any case they are a bad idea and should be avoided. You just need a function that returns new record values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why prefer a naked function over a record constructor?

Comment: @J... A constructor is special. When you invoke it, a new object is instantiated and then initialised. On the other hand, a record constructor just initialises. It does not instantiate. I'm used to seeing code like, `obj := TMyClass.Create` and knowing that I need to pair it with a call to `obj.Free`. That's not the case with records. I find that using `rec := TMyRec.Create` causes confusion. Is `obj` a value type or a reference type? By reserving the use of constructors to reference types, I can be confident that I know what I am dealing with.

Comment: @J... Another problem is that parameterless constructors are not allowed on records. If you are a `FreeAndNil`er then you can get caught out by accidentally passing your record to `FreeAndNil`. Actually that's really a reason to stop using `FreeAndNil` isn't it? Finally, I don't like that I can call constructors on instances. I can just write `rec.Create(666);`. I'd rather not allow that. My convention is a static class method named `New`. So I would initialise a record like this: `rec := TMyRec.New`. By following that convention I find it's easier to be sure I know what I am dealing with.

Comment: @J... Now in this instance the asker is using Delphi 7 and can use neither constructors nor static class functions. Naked function is the only choice for him.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on the idea of refactoring to use a parameter object, you could declare a record like:

```
 TSetMarkParams = record
   x0 : double; 
   y0 : double; 
   TextOffset : integer;
   TextBefore : string;
   Text : string;
   TextAfter : string;
   Color : string;
   ArrowPresent : boolean;
   constructor Create(Ax0, Ay0 : double);
 end;
```

And implement the constructor to populate default values as :

```
 constructor TSetMarkParams.Create(Ax0, Ay0 : double);
 begin
   x0 := Ax0;
   y0 := Ay0;
   TextOffset := 5;
   TextBefore := '';
   Text := '';
   TextAfter := 'mm';
   Color := 'FFFFFF';
   AllowPresent := true;
 end;
```

Your procedure would then have signature :

```
 procedure SetMark(ASetMarkParams : TSetMarkParams);
```

Which you could then, using your example of `SetMark (15, 100,,,'135');` call as :

```
 var 
   LSetMarkParams : TSetMarkParams
 begin
   LSetMarkParams := TSetMarkParams.Create(15, 100);
   LSetMarkParams.Text := '135';
   SetMark(LSetMarkParams);
 end;
```

As collateral benefit, the above is much more readable as it saves you from going blind trying to count commas when returning to debug a troublesome method call.