# Accessing a Scala method "default()" from Java code

Tags: java, scala, compatibility

It appears that I'm unable to access a Scala method `default()` from Java code.

```
scala> class A {
     | def default = 3
     | }
defined class A

scala> :javap -public A
Compiled from "<console>"
public class A {
  public int default();
  public A();
}
```

Trying to access `default()` in Java code yields all kind of syntax errors. Is there a workaround like Scala's backticks to handle Java keywords?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423994/reserved-words-as-variable-or-method-names

Comment: I was hoping Scala might do some magic here. When working with IntelliJ it offers `_mthdefault()` as auto complete option. The method doesn't really exist, though. Therefore it does not compile or show up in javap. I'm just hoping I'm overlooking something here.

Comment: Maybe with reflection, but otherwise, I don't think so.