# Create dynamic classes with reserved words as variables

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode, javassist

This question was once asked without a satisfactory answer besides "why would you want to do this" at [Reserved words as variable or method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423994/reserved-words-as-variable-or-method-names).  I'm going to ask it again, and provide context that explains why it is necessary, and even the direction to a proper solution.

I am writing code that builds classes dynamically to match the schema of a database, which I have no control over.  For the most part, the code is working cleanly, but in about .1% of the column cases, there are reserved words in Java being used as column names.  The following code is being used to create the dynamic field in the class:

evalClass.addField(CtField.make("public " + columnType + " " + columnName + ";", evalClass));

Now, with Java the language, this results in an issue, however in JVM byte code, this should be perfectly legal, so there should be a way to dynamically create this field and access it using byte-code operations.  Does anybody have any examples of how this would be done in a way that would support arbitrary strings, including spaces and reserved words?  Thanks!

Comment: That question absolutely has a satisfactory answer: [*"No, there is no way."*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/424002/157247) The distinction between your question and that one is that you're not trying to do it at the *source code level*. I suggest editing to move that information to the foreground, and only mention the other question at the end saying "I saw this, but it's asking about source code, and I'm asking about doing it at the bytecode level since we can't do it at the source code level."

Comment: I still don't understand why this is necessary. Every persistence architecture I can think of provides straightforward techniques for mapping field / bean property names to arbitrary column names, and avoiding Java keyword field names is one of the reasons for providing that. Sure you're generating classes from a schema but the concept is the same. Why do your field names have to be the same as column names? Why don't you just e.g. add a prefix to all your field names (or just to reserved words) or something instead?

Comment: Even if you could generate the classes, what purpose would they serve? You couldn't use those fields in any source code you wrote. The whole thing sounds like a really good way to waste a lot of time. Spend that time building the mappings Jason mentioned into your persistence architecture (and/or perhaps ask yourself why you're writing your own persistence architecture).

Comment: @Jason C, the issue in my case is that the SQL where predicates need to map to the data structure exactly, AND map to the table's column name exactly to prevent more layers of abstraction (and reduced performance) from being added in.  The code in question is acting below the JDBC api level (it is in fact a JDBC driver), so existing abstraction mechanisms would already have translated to the actual table name at this point.

Comment: @ErikBrandsberg Still seems strange... I'm sure you have a reason to be doing what you're doing but it looks like you're already adding an extra layer of abstraction? You're creating these internal mapped classes, but ultimately you're just going to be delivering them back to the application via a `ResultSet` -- which provides information per-column as a VO, not per-row as a POJO/bean -- where they will likely once *again* be mapped to application-side classes. But in any case, is it simple enough to just e.g. prefix all your field names with an "_" and strip it away? Plus, Antimony's answer.

Comment: (And no, I'm not demanding that you justify your reasoning, I know that's a super annoying demand. I'm just saying, it seems unusual to me to have to do something like this at the driver level, perhaps there are other approaches to consider, such as letting whatever DBMS you're writing a driver for do more of the work and dealing with sending/receiving raw data directly and reflection-less).

Comment: @Jason C, more details--the data is actually being stored into Hazelcast, and the where queries from SQL requests passed into Hazelcast for queries to offload the database.  Thus, we need classes that represent the tables (which we also have no control over), and the SQL predicates will process out of the cache.  This clarify a bit, and why renaming the fields isn't the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which part you are stuck on. Any bytecode manipulation library should let you do this.

For example, using ASM, you just pass your string directly to visitField. There's no hoops to jump through or anything.

Note that even at the bytecode level, there are still a few restrictions on field names. In particular, they can't be more than 65535 bytes long in MUTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You picked the only way where this doesn’t work—Javassist’s source level API. It should be obvious to you that if you use the identifier to construct source code, the identifier must adhere to the source code rules. Besides, using the already known intended structure to construct source code which has to be parsed again to reconstitute the intention, is the most inefficient way of processing byte code.

You can use the [Bytecode level API](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#intro) to overcome these limitations. As a side note, most other byte code processing libraries do not have a source level API at all, so with them you would have used a byte code level API right from the start.

That said, you should rethink your premise. Generated classes whose fields can only be accessed via Reflection or other generated code, do not offer any advantage over, e.g. a `HashMap` mapping from identifiers to values or arrays intrinsically associating columns with positions.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, it seemed Javassist was the easy way to get the functionality needed, and for 99.9% of the case, it works.  As this particular piece of functionality only needs to be used to setup the classes, performance wasn't a primary factor.  On the premise, this code is driver-level code at the JDBC level, and we don't control the fields, and are also using other code from a partner that relies on the fields matching what is in the database.  As such, changing the field names would be more painful than just making this work.

Comment: Well, the source level API not only is more expensive in terms of performance, it also opens more possibilities of introducing errors. It’s not only sensitive to field names matching keywords, also adding fields with names matching type names can make the *next* declarations fail spuriously.