# Java - is it possible to declare a serialized key by the name "static"

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I wanted to create a POJO which I will later want to convert it to JSON using GSON. My JSON looks like this

```
{
"static":"value",
"otherkey": "value"
}
```

So my POJO looks likes this

```
public class MyPOJO {

    public String static;
    public String otherkey;
}
```

But the complier complains me at this `public String static;`. I know static is a keyword but is it possible?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423994/reserved-words-as-variable-or-method-names

Comment: You can use annotations to separate your java field names and json names.  This allows you to rename either one of them without affecting the other.

Comment: @Christine Thanks! did that.

Comment: @VinayakBevinakatti can you please look at my recent code?

Comment: @moocow Where's your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't name it static because it's a reserved keyword, just like the other answers say. To solve your problem with GSON, use the [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation to specify the name used during serialization, and don't name the variable `static`, pick something else like so:

```
@SerializedName("static")
private String myStaticVar;
```

Answer (score 4):

"static" is a reserved word. You cannot use it for variable.

Comment: So how do I solve my problem

Comment: @VinayakBevinakatti Name it something else, then specify the [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot: `static` is a reserved keyword.

You can use names like: `statik`, `static_`, ...

Use `@SerializedName("static")` to specify the name to use in the JSON output:

```
@SerializedName("static")
public String statik;
```