# Dealing with String array elements in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

So I have this particular code:

```
import java.util.*;

class insertWordInMiddle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s = "Python 3.0";
        String s_split[] = s.split(" ");

        String a = new String(s_split[0]);
        String b = new String(s_split[1]);

        String c = a + " Tutorial " + b;
        System.out.println(c);
        
    }
}
```

I was practising and I wanted to insert a word between two words (in the form of a string). It works, however I have yet other way of doing this but cannot get why it doesn't work:

```
import java.util.*;

class insertWordInMiddle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s = "Python 3.0";
        String s_split[] = s.split(" ");
        String final = s_split[0]+" Tutorial "+s_split[1];

        System.out.println(final);
    }
}
```

Error:

> /home/reeshabh/Desktop/java practice/insertWordInMiddle.java:14:
>
> error: not a statement
>
> String final = s_split[0]+" Tutorial"+s_split[1];

Comment: final is a reserved keyword

Comment: `final` is a keyword. Don't use that as a variable name.

Comment: `new String(s_split[0])` is unnecessary: `s_split[0]` is sufficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/424014/6722100 for a full list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that final can't be the name of a variable. I can go into more detail if needed, but that's pretty much it. Try something else for your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

`final` is a reserved keyword in Java. You can't name a variable `final`. Try renaming it to e.g. `finalString`.

[Wikipedia has a list of all the reserved keywords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords#List).

Answer (score 0):

`final` is a keyword. You can't use it as a variable name.

As per the building of strings: you could use `StringBuilder`, but for generating one string it's not really necessary. However, concatenating strings using the `+` operator will create copies of all strings involved and make baby cry when used within a loop.

[When to use StringBuilder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You was just a bit unlucky - you used word that is reserved for other purposes in Java language. Take a look at this list, `final` is present here, so you can't name variables with words listed there:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html