# How to "escape" the JavaScript class keyword to specify a CSS class value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

**C# allows a reserved word to be used as a property name** [via the at sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-keyword-as-a-property-on-an-anonymous-object).  e.g.

```
// In ASP.NET MVC, we use @class to define 
// the css class attribute for some HtmlHelper methods.
var htmlObject = new { readonly = "readonly", @class = "ui-state-highlight" }
```

I want to do the same in JavaScript.  e.g.

```
function makeGrid(grid, pager) {
    grid.jqGrid({
        caption: 'Configurations',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id' },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true, 
              editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly', class: 'FormElement readonly' } },
          ],
        pager: pager,
        url: 'www.example.com/app/configurations") %>',
        editurl: 'www.example.com/app/configurations/edit") %>'
    }).navGrid(pager, { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {});
}
```

Note ***class: 'FormElement readonly'*** is supposed to set the css class value on jqGrid's edit dialog, but IE errors out on the reserved word.

**Is there an escape character in JavaScript too?  #class? @class? &class?**  Otherwise, how might I tell jqGrid to set the css class on the popup editor?  Thank you.

Comment: Btw., '@' is not an ampersand, '&' is an ampersand (in the first paragraph).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think in this context, quoting class should work as it's the name of a property on an object literal i.e.

```
editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly', 'class': 'FormElement readonly' } },
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know jqGrid but I would imagine 'class' would work.

Answer (score 1):

Use "className".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @class in jQuery