# dynamic json return "long" as object property

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I write a code to fetch a Web service that return outpot as JSON in C#, when the output is captured, I convert it into dynamic datatype, and then in my code I write something

```
dynamic myobj = FetchFromWeb("some weburl");
string value1 = myobj.property1[0].sub-property.finalvaluething; //This works
string value2 = myobj.property1[0].sub-property.long; //This produce error that long is keyword
```

the last statement above, gives error that "long" is keyword and cannot be used as identifier. My question is how can I get that value, as in my Json object long is used as name of variable.

I try to use `myobj.property1[0].sub-property.GetProperty("long").GetValue()` but it too doesn't work and give error. Any idea how can I access that property. It is hard to get variable name changed from source.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@` symbol to escape the keyword.

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse("{'long':'value'}");
string longValue = data.@long;
Console.WriteLine(longValue); // value
```

See [How do I use a C# keyword as a property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-on-an-anonymous-object)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `dynamic` object is really a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) from Json.NET, one of these will work:

```
long l1 = d["long"];
long l2 = d.GetValue("long");
long l3 = d.Value<long>("long");
```

Edit: Or, as Romoku suggested, `d.@long`. I have mixed feelings about this one, however, since the `@` symbol is not (AFAIK) widely used or known in this capacity, and thus might confuse people who read the code. If you have the option to, I'd go with a more explicit lookup-by-string like the three above.

Comment: No I don't use Json.Net here. but "@" works fine for me.