# how to deserialize "ref" parameter

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-deserialization, jive

I'm trying to parse a json file that contains a parameter named ref. I'm deserializing into a class structure:

```
public class JiveContentObject
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public string subject { get; set;}
   ..etc
}
```

however, I can't exactly write `public string ref {get; set;}` since `ref` is a keyword in c#. Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: just write `@ref`. prepending `@` is how you work around reserved keywords. however it would be better to make use of some kind of middleware mapping

Comment: A question that is not a duplicate of this one, but whose accepted answer applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-on-an-anonymous-object

Answer (score 7):

Prefix the identifier with `@`:

```
public class JiveContentObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string @ref { get; set; }
}
```

This is exactly what it's there for.