# c# Using params variable name in Class

Tags: c#

I have the following Class definition:

```
class PostObject
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public MyObject params { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

I use this class for a post call (serialized in json) and the server has '**params**' as an input post var and there's no way to change it.

The question is that as **params** is a reserved keyword in c#, what should I do?

Comment: `@params` would escape the keyword

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a C# keyword as a property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-name)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWatts. Works fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use serialization attributes to set it's name. Like this (NewtonSoft.Json):

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "params")]
public MyObject parameters { get; set; }
```

[Serialization Attributes in NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

Comment: This is definitely the better way to do it, so you can use "C# style" property names, just didnt want to assume (in my comment) that OP was using newtonsoft!

Answer (score 5):

Please see MSDN for the same. You can still use keywords as variable name but by appending '@'. Example :- int @int= 100;

Source,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Answer (score 1):

Other than the `@` escape and `JsonPropertyAttribute`, it is also worth mentioning that you don't need to follow the exact capitalization with a library like `NewtonSoft.Json`:

```
public string Params { get; set; }
```