# Use params keyword in anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Can i use params keyword in an anonymous object? ASP.NET MVC doesn't allow it. Is there any solution?

```
 //It gives an error for "params" keyword.
 var rv = new { params= "test it" };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre prepend keywords with an '@':

```
var rv = new { @params= "test it" };
```

See also: [How do I use a C# keyword as a property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-name)