# Why does Rider add an "@" to my public variable?

Tags: c#, rider

I've declared a class like this:

```
public class Cell : IEquatable<Cell>
{
    public int id { get; }
    public SetOfCells group;
}
```

And each time I want to use `group`, Rider adds and `@` before, like this:

```
foreach (Cell cell in c1.@group) {
    /* blabla */
}
```

Precision: `c1.@group` and `c1.group` *both* works. Why is that?

(if you can tell me the right words to google to find a valuable answer I'm interested, because I couldn't find one: "`csharp property +"@"` doesn't help...")

Comment: I feel that is a weird behavior specific to Rider, because in Visual Studio, it doesn't detect that particular usage as the `group` keyword.  It has to be used within a LINQ query for it to be detected as a keyword.

Comment: @OlivierPons the `@` character used like this in C# is called 'verbatim identifier' or 'verbatim prefix': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`group` is a keyword in C# (for the LINQ [group clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/group-clause)), and `@` is the ["verbatim prefix"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) used by C# to [use keywords as identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421263/87698) (e.g. `int @int = 3;`).

In this case, the `@` is not necessary: `group` was added as a keyword in a later version of C#, so the C# compiler had to remain backwards-compatible with existing code and accept `group` in situations where other keywords such as `int` would not be allowed:

```
var int = 3;    // won't compile
var group = 3;  // compiles
```

`group` is a so-called ["contextual keyword"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/).

I cannot answer *why* Rider adds `@` in front of `group`. I *suspect* that Rider tries to "play it safe" and adds a `@` in front of every usage of a C# keyword as an identifier (as you have found out, it doesn't hurt).

A pragmatic solution would be to rename your member to `Group` (with a capitalized `G`).

Comment: Probably an implementation decision in Rider favouring pragmatism over more accurate but also more costly implementation of various refactoring. Seems like a few people reported this in the past (5 years ago): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-459185