# How to use C# keyword inside a object as key of a field?

Tags: c#, .net-core, gupshup

I think I have a very unique problem here.

I am using a message service to send WhatsApp messages to our opted-in users.

The vendor's API to send message has the following body structure:

```
'template={"id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","params": []}'
```

The problem is, whenever I try make call to this API from C# (a dotnet core project), I get error because `params` is a keyword in c#.

So when I try the following the code, it throws error that it is a keyword.

```
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("template", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = templateId, params = [] })));
```

How to survive this deadly problem?

Comment: Use `@params` to describe an identifier named `params`

Comment: It should be `new { id = templateId, @params = Array.Empty<object>() }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/421263/12576990

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the time when I was not aware how to search my problem. Thank you very very much.