# how to create a properties with same name as .net reserved keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net

My API Response json has below fields when I paste JSON as classes it created the one of the field as  _class as **class** is a reserved keyword

- **Actual**

public class Imp
{

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    **public string _class { get; set; }**
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public decimal highest { get; set; }
}
```

but my requirement is to have field as class only, Could anyone suggest how to achieve this?

- **Desired**

public class Imp
{

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string class { get; set; } 
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public decimal highest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-name or few others internet search for "c# use reserved word as variable" answered here already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string @class {get;set;}
```

However, convention would be to call it `Class` instead, in which case: no problem in the first place. If serialization is the problem, most serializers have attributes to help with that:

```
[JsonProperty("class")]
public string Class {get;set;}
```

(or whatever your serializer uses)