# Is it possible to use the name `class` as a Blazor component's parameter name?

Tags: c#, blazor, razor-components

I would like to be able to use the parameter name `class` for a Blazor component:

```
<MyComponent class="my-css-class" />
```

I tried to implement it like this:

```
<div class="@class">
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? class { get; set; }
}
```

However, since `class` is a reserved keyword in C#, it makes the IDE and compiler confused:

[image]

Is it possible somehow to use `class` as a parameter name?

Comment: The [standard workaround of using a keyword as an identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421257/5133585) should work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/splat-attributes-and-arbitrary-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you truly wanted to use `class` as a property name instead of `Class`, then you could escape the reserved keyword in the usual way by prefixing it with an `@`, and then wrap any references to it in the razor with parentheses.

```
<div class="@(@class)">
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? @class { get; set; }
}
```

Personally I would just go with C# naming conventions though:

```
<div class="@Class">
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Class { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to add a parameter in the Razor component that captures unmatched values:

```cs
[Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? Attributes { get; set; }
```

It is possible to get and use the `class` parameter in the Razor component by rewriting it like this:

```
<div class="@CssClass">
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? Attributes { get; set; }

    string CssClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (Attributes != null &&
                Attributes.TryGetValue("class", out var @class) &&
                Convert.ToString(@class) is { } classString &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(classString))
            {
                return classString;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you may use the Razor component and set its `class` parameter:

```
<MyComponent class="my-css-class" />
```

Comment: Or just use C# naming conventions and declare your property as `Class` ;)